# Scala: Get companion class in companion object

Tags: scala, companion-object

I need to define a val in my companion object which is initialized with a method which takes the companion class as parameter.

I want to handle this with traits to not repeat myself. My Problem ist, that X.getClass ist not the same as classOf[X]. The first is the class of the companion object and the second is the class of the companion class, but I need to get the companion class without hardcoding it directly.

Basically I need something like this:

```
trait Foo {

}

object FooCompanionObject[f <: Foo] {
    val fClazz = classOf[f]
}

// Bar's fClass should be classOf[Bar]
case class Bar extends Foo;

object Bar extends FooCompanionObject[Bar];
```

The problem is that I cannot get the class of an generic type due to type erasure

Comment: Why are you adding a generic type declaration to an object. Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: My object will have some methods that will return an f.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several problems in your code. First, as you already said, the type will be erased, second `object`s (`object FooCompanionObject[f <: Foo]`) don't take type parameters and third, `object`s can not be extended (`object Bar extends FooCompanionObject`). To do what you want, you have to create an abstract base class for your companion objects, that takes a type parameter, which may be constrained to a specific type if you like, and has to be context bound on `ClassTag`. From the `ClassTag` you can then get the runtime class by calling `runtimeClass` on it. The final solution could look like this:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.classTag

trait Foo

abstract class Companion[A <: Foo : ClassTag] {
  val fClazz = classTag[A].runtimeClass
}

class Bar extends Foo
object Bar extends Companion[Bar]


scala> Bar.fClazz
res2: Class[_] = class Bar
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a ClassOf[A] ? (Typesafe)